# PHP/Laravel - Extending authorizeResource to work on custom method

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **resource controller** called `StreamController.php`, that utilizes a policy called `StreamPolicy.php`.

In my controller, I have this:

```
    //StreamController.php
    /**
     * Construct method.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->authorizeResource(Stream::class, 'stream');
    }
```

With above, all the RESTful endpoints is successfully "protected" using the policy.

However, I have added a new method to my controller, called `documents()`, like so:

```
//web.php
Route::get('streams/{stream}/documents', 'StreamController@documents');
```

```
    //StreamController.php
    /**
     * Display the imported documents of the resource
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function documents(Stream $stream)
    {
        return view('streams.documents', compact('stream'));
    }
```

Now the problem is if I visit the URL:

**example.com/streams/1** and I am not the owner of the stream, I get a 403 page - **but** if I go to:
**example.com/streams/1/documents** and I am not the owner of the stream, I can still access the page.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make so my policy also covers the `documents()` methods in my controller?

**Edit:**

This is my `StreamPolicy.php` file:

```
//StreamPolicy.php
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Stream;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class StreamPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the stream.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Stream  $stream
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Stream $stream)
    {
        return $user->id == $stream->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create streams.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        //
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the stream.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Stream  $stream
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Stream $stream)
    {
        //

        return $user->id == $stream->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the stream.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Stream  $stream
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Stream $stream)
    {
        //

        return $user->id == $stream->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can restore the stream.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Stream  $stream
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function restore(User $user, Stream $stream)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the stream.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Stream  $stream
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function forceDelete(User $user, Stream $stream)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try `Route::get('streams/{stream}/documents', 'StreamPolicy', 'StreamController@documents');`

Comment: That gives me `Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\StreamPolicy]`

Comment: ok.. then.. another way would be to check if the StreamPolicy has the `documents` method which actually calls the `read` method inside the policy

Comment: I don't see any `read` method in the policy. However I tried to add a `documents` method inside my StreamPolicy. But that did not change anything

Comment: What version of laravel do you have?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.7.

Comment: Can you please include the streampolicy class in the question?

Comment: @MateiMihai - just added it!

Comment: adding: `public function documents(User $user, Stream $stream)
    {
        return $this->view($user, $stream);
    }` does nothing?

Comment: No, I can still access the URL (/documents) even if I am not the owner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know exactly why is not working but I'm afraid that the `authorizeResource` method only handles the routes for the well-known resources end-points: view, create, update, delete and restore.

*Later edit*: Take a look in the docs to see which are the actions handled by the Resource Controllers https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers

What you should do is to explicitly set the authorization to the new route:

```
Route::get('streams/{stream}/documents', 'StreamController@documents')->middleware('can:documents,stream');
```

Of course, the `documents` method should exist on the `StreamPolicy` class.

**OR**

To authorize inside the `StreamController.documents` method:

```
public function documents(Stream $stream)
{
    $this->authorize('documents', $stream);

    return view('streams.documents', compact('stream'));
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Controller.php uses "AuthorizesRequest" trait which defines below 2 methods:

```
trait AuthorizesRequests
{
  /**
 * Get the map of resource methods to ability names.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function resourceAbilityMap()
{
    return [
        'show' => 'view',
        'create' => 'create',
        'store' => 'create',
        'edit' => 'update',
        'update' => 'update',
        'destroy' => 'delete',
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the list of resource methods which do not have model parameters.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function resourceMethodsWithoutModels()
{
    return ['index', 'create', 'store'];
}
```

You can override these 2 protected methods per controller basis because every controller extends Controller.php

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource ( User::class, 'user' );
    }

   /**
     * Get the map of resource methods to ability names.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function resourceAbilityMap()
    {
        return [
            'show' => 'view',
            'create' => 'create',
            'store' => 'create',
            'edit' => 'update',
            'update' => 'update',
            'destroy' => 'delete',
            'customMethod'=>'customMethod',
            'customMethodWithoutModel'=>'customMethodWithoutModel'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of resource methods which do not have model parameters.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function resourceMethodsWithoutModels()
    {
        return ['index', 'create', 'store','customMethodWithoutModel'];
    }
```

Its Policy Class

```
class UserPolicy
{

   /**
     * Determine whether the user can custom method.
     *
     * @param  \App\User $user
     * @param  \App\User $model
     * @return mixed
     */
   public function customMethod(User $user, User $model){
        return true; 
   }

   /**
     * Determine whether the user can custom method without model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User $user
     * @return mixed
     */
   public function customMethodWithoutModel(User $user){
        return true;
   }
```

Comment: How do you pass extra parameters to the custom policy method?

Comment: You can not pass extra parameters to a custom policy method as they are injected by the framework. The first one is the authenticated user i.e. `User $user` and the second one is the resolved model against a resource route i.e. `User $user`. You either need to create a service or add them in current request and access them through request helper function. If you need to access a nested resource route then access your resolved model through `request()->route('model_param_name')`. e.g. `request()->route('post')`

Comment: This answer should be accepted because it follows the Laravel standard.